# How can I print Qrcode in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I made a code that generate a QRcode. 
And now I'm trying to print it in thermal paper . But how can i print it specific size of paper? Thank you

```
Private Sub GraphicPrint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs)

    Dim x As Integer = 60
    Dim y As Integer = 60
    Dim width As Integer = 100
    Dim height As Integer = 50


    ' e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(GraphicLocation.Text), x, y, width, height, e.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds)
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(GraphicLocation.Text), x, y, width, height)
    e.HasMorePages = False
End Sub


Private Sub BeginGraphicPrint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BeginGraphicPrint.Click
    Try
        AddHandler PrintGraphicControl.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.GraphicPrint
        PrintGraphicControl.Print()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: use the pagesetup control.

Comment: @DannyJames do you think it will work in a thermal papaer? Thank you

Comment: @DannyJames do you think it will work in a thermal papaer? Thank you

Comment: as long as your dpi setting is reasonable, you should have no problems scanning it.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics    
    ' Draw image to screen.
    g.DrawImage(Piccode.Image, 0, 0, 100, 100)
End Sub
```